# "Process was not attached to console" in ConEmu

Tags: conemu

Since yesterday I started getting error "Process was not attached to console" when I try to open a cygwin-bash console. The problem is debilitating and described at https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/2495.

Please help!

Here are some details copied from the issue:

It opens `cmd` and `github bash` but not `cygwin bash`. Here's the problem screen:

```
ConEmuC64: Process was not attached to console. Is it GUI?

Current directory:
C:\Users\Vladimir Alexiev

Command to be executed:
C:\PROGRA~1\ConEmu\ConEmu\conemu-cyg-64.exe C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --login -i


Press Ctrl+Break to stop waiting


Press Enter or Esc to exit...
```

Command to open Cygwin Bash (I think that's the default one):

```
*set CHERE_INVOKING=1 & set "PATH=C:\cygwin64\bin;%PATH%" & %ConEmuBaseDirShort%\conemu-cyg-64.exe -new_console:p C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --login -i -new_console:C:"C:\cygwin64\Cygwin.ico"
```

- I haven't made any changes and this was working a couple days ago.
- CYGWIN_NT-10.0-19045
- ConEmu version: 230724 Stable. Last successful update : Mon 07/24/2023  12:04 PM
- "Update Check" and https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/releases says that's the latest version

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: All details are in the linked issue, I didn't want to repeat them. But I'll copy a bit to avoid being scolded by a bot :-)

Comment: @VladimirAlexiev It's important to repeat all content on SE sites since there's no guarantee the link to external content will be available in a year, 5yrs, 10yrs, etc. which can be problematic when a user comes across this question years from now